# Is raspberry pi 2 model B a good candidate as a "Download Box" or NAS

Tags: raspbian, networking, server, performance, pi-2

I am planning to buy **Raspberry pi 2 Model B**. Predominantly for two purposes,

1. **Download Box** (for Torrents, ftp / http downloads)
2. Web Server (For replying some requests to Local Client computers ) and sometimes it will be used as an intermediate to share files between devices inside Lan with an attached HDD to it.

Please note that it will be 24/7 powered on most of the time and connected directly to the router via ethernet cable.

My budget is maximum $40-45. Will Raspberry Pi perfectly work for this purpose? or any other board would you suggest? If you have used it, what average practical internet download speed do you get?

UPDATE: I have 12 Mbit/s internet connection plan. So, I expect getting practical minimum download speed of **1.5 MB/s**.

Answer (score 2):

> what average practical internet download speed do you get?

Obviously you won't get more than the 100BASE-T speed, i.e., 12 MB/s.  In reality, I wouldn't expect more than half that, but it is hard to say since most real internet connections in my experience won't sustain this anyway -- but I don't torrent.

My LAN transfers to/from the pi's USB drive are pretty slow, 3-4 MB/s, I suspect because I do them via sshfs.

In short, if you are shuffling gigabytes of stuff on a daily basis you will be disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not your connection speed, it is file storage.  You need a place to store the files you want to download and share.  And for the budget you're proposing, I don't think you can get the RPi by itself to do the job unless you are happy to just share small files.

I would imagine these are possible solutions for storage...

- Buy an expensive SD card ($30 for 32G).
- Buy a large USB memory stick (also not cheap)
- Mount an existing networked drive, such as a shared drive on an existing machine
- Buy an external USB drive known to work, such as http://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/accessories/hard-drives/seagate-320gb-2.5-external-hard-drive-rpi-tested (not cheap, requires separate USB hub)

Comment: Obviously I am going to save contents in attached HDD (which I already have).

Comment: Then sure, it's going to be fine for your need.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi 2 is perfect for your requirements. I bought my RPI2 for this purpose and have set it up to do pretty much this.

Services I run on the RPI2:

- Apache Web Server with TLS/HTTPS.
- Torrent client - Transmission BT with web interface.
- PPTP VPN.
- Cloud/File Transfer services : ownCloud, Seafile, Pydio, Tonido.
- Simple Machines Forum.
- DLNA

I run this 24/7 without any personal maintenance at all, although I do run backup and other automated scheduled maintenances every day. I have mounted an external HDD connected via a powered USB hub and it too works perfectly all the time. I am running it from a >90 Mbps (up/down) WAN connection and gives 3-4 MBps download speeds and 7-8 MBps upload speeds when connecting remotely. Connected via LAN using SCP gives me about 6-7 MBps download speeds and 8-9 MBps upload speeds.

My website running on the RPI2 : https://pavinjoseph.com

Comment: Thanks Joseph for your Inputs. I appreciate it. Can you please explain me "Connected via LAN using SCP..... ". I don't get it. Do you mean you are getting that speed inside LAN ?

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Yes. I am getting those increased speeds when uploading/downloading files over LAN using [SCP - Secure Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy)  protocol. On Windows you can use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) for GUI SCP or [PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) for command-line SCP